# Podman Apache 403 Forbidden

Tags: linux, apache, debian, lamp, podman

I've installed LAMP server inside Podman containers. I have mapped my `~/Projects` folder as the http root (directing to `/var/www/html` inside the container) and the access works fine when I do `http://localhost:8080`.

However, I have my project files inside `/mnt/projects/www` folder for lack of space in that drive. I created a symlink (`www`) to that folder inside my `~/Projects` so I can access my project files like `http://localhost:8080/www`. But I get a `403 Forbidden` error when I do that.

`/mnt/Projects` folder is owned by group `data` and user is a member of that group.

`/mnt/Projects/www` folder is owned by the user with 777 access.

`~/Projects` is owned by the user with 755 access.

How do I set up the permissions for this access to work?

Comment: For the person that voted to close this question: I have thoroughly researched this situation and could not find an answer anywhere. If you know the solution, you can help by sharing the same. If you don't, you could pass this question so anyone who knows can answer. Voting to close will only block people from helping and doing so without explaining the reason is viewed as sheer arrogance. Sad to see such arrogant people among this amazing SO community.